# OpenCL: Confusing Results according local_item_size

Tags: c++, c, matrix, opencl

My code acts like 2d matrix muliplication ( http://gpgpu-computing4.blogspot.de/2009/09/matrix-multiplication-2-opencl.html).
The dimenstions of the matrixes are (1000*1000 and 10000*10000 and 100000*100000).

My Hardware is:  NVIDIA Corporation GM204 [GeForce GTX 980] (MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZES: 1024 1024 64).

The question is:

I have got Some Confusing Results depends on local_item_size and I need to understand what is happened?

- 1000 X 1000 matrixes & local_item_size = 16 : **INVALID_WORKGROUP_SIZE**.
- 1000 X 1000 matrixes & local_item_size = 8 : WORKS :).
- 1000 X 1000 matrixes & local_item_size = 10 : WORKS :) (The Execution time when 8 was better).
- 10000 X 10000 matrixes & local_item_size = 8 or 16: **CL_OUT_OF_RESOURCES**.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: @buttifulbuttefly, I did http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30593848/opencl-determine-the-best-local-item-size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To your second question, this is the reasoning behind:

- 1000 / 8 = 125, ok
- 1000 / 16 = 62.5, wrong! INVALID_WORKGROUP_SIZE
- 1000 / 10 = 100 ok, but 10 and multiples of 10, will never fully use the GPU cores.

  - IE: If you have 16 warps, 6 are wasted, if you have 32, 2 are wasted, and so on.
- 10000x10000 = 400MB(at least, if using floats) for just the input, so something is getting too big for the memory, therefore CL_OUT_OF_RESOURCES

Comment: thx but how did you get 400MB? and how can I get the maximum possible memory size?

Comment: well, 10kx10k=100M, but those are elements, if each element is float or int32, it will be 4 bytes size, so 400MB. And is only for one input, if you have 2 inputs and an output will be 1200MB.